# Optimize sql query for endswith

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy

I have a table called **Requests**, where there are multiple columns and a **url** column particularly.

I have a query using sqlalchemy:

```
request_return = self.session.query(Requests).filter(Requests.url.endswith('register'))\
            .order_by(desc(Requests.request_time))
```

The motive is to return rows of data whose **url** column's value ends with 'register'.

Example: It returns value with: https://urlname.com/users/register

Printing the **request_return** gives me this raw sql query:

```
SELECT requests.id AS requests_id, requests.identifier AS requests_identifier, requests.url AS requests_url, requests.status_code AS requests_status_code, requests.response_time AS requests_response_time, requests.response_size AS requests_response_size, requests.labels AS requests_labels, requests.method AS requests_method, requests.request_time AS requests_request_time, requests.user_id AS requests_user_id, requests.request_metadata AS requests_request_metadata 
FROM requests 
WHERE (requests.url LIKE '%%' || %(url_1)s) ORDER BY requests.request_time DESC
```

The problem with this is that it performs a scan, thus performance is extremely slow. There might be some workaround with indexing to make this efficient. I need some suggestions on how could I go about it.

Comment: This is not really SQLAlchemy related but more database optimization. Consider to ask on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com). But the duplicate gives some direction. One answer suggests to generate a `reversed` index and search for reverse. In SQLAlchemy this can be achieved as: `request_return = elf.session.query(Requests).filter(Requests.url.endswith(func.reverse('register')))      .order_by(desc(Requests.request_time))` and create the index as follows: rev_idx = Index(
    'rev_idx1',
    func.reverse(tbl.c.url).label('rev_url'),
    postgresql_ops={'rev_url': 'text_pattern_ops'},
)

Comment: okay will try the reversed index one, thanks.